# Change plugin model and migrate data

Tags: django, django-cms

During implementation of one of our projects, we have made the mistake of subclassing Link class instead of using the CMSPlugin parent and some form of abstract class mix-in.

One solution may be to do a migration and change the model's fields (as described in https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5237#issuecomment-217426949), however, it seems to me that simple(r) solution may be to just create new models and upgrade the plugins accordingly.

My proposed workflow is:

- create new models
- for each of the existing models, copy over all of the fields to the new models

What I am not sure is how to set up the Django CMS plugins - at which point should I change the plugin's model? And how to ensure that the newly created models are also linked properly to the previous plugins?

Comment: Is the project live? You could just correct (re-start) the migrations for that application if the system hasn't launched yet.

Comment: It is - it's an existing site with quite a bit of content